# Origin of scientific racism?

Tags: 18th-century, science, racism, enlightenment

[Modern scientific racism became wide spread during the age of enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_racism). Is there a single person that could be labeled as the 'father' of modern scientific racism?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69035/discussion-on-question-by-tlen-origin-of-scientific-racism).

Comment: Could you specify precisely what meaning of "scientific racism" you intend?

Comment: @Willem basically using scientific arguments to justify calling other group of people inferior, e.g. the things polygenists were doing

Comment: @Tien Inferior in what sense? "On average, Kenyans are superior runners as compared to Koreans"?

Comment: @Tien, you're taking me in bad faith. Definitions matter a lot, without them language is worthless and devolves into a mere instrument of power, and not communication. Racism has many definitions, and is both morally and politically charged. That's why it's important to precisely define it.

Comment: @Tien. I can understand why some people want to close this, but I think there's a good question hiding in here somewhere. I'm not sure how to improve it though...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's no universally recognised "father of scientific racism", though a number of names could be suggested.

One example is the French noble [**Arthur de Gobineau**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_de_Gobineau), best remembered today for pioneering the concept of an [Aryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan_race) master race. His infamous [*An Essay on the Inequality of the Human Races*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_on_the_Inequality_of_the_Human_Races), published in 1853, inspired a host of other racial theories including those of the Nazis. This has led some to label Gobineau as "the earliest significant intellectual racist"<sup>**[1]**</sup> or the "father of racist ideologies"<sup>**[2]**</sup>.

While credited to Gobineau today, precursors to the master race concept can be traced much further back to [**Henri de Boulainvilliers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_de_Boulainvilliers) in the early 18th century. Also a French aristocrat, Boulainvilliers argued that the [Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franks) nobility of France are racially superior to the [Gaulish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauls) underclass. He originated the concept of measuring skulls to determine race, claiming that Germanic aristocratic skulls were larger<sup>**[3]**</sup> - a practice later made infamous by the Nazis.

The Swedish biologist [**Carolus Linnæus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Linnaeus), better known as the "father of modern taxonomy" today, provides another early example. His [Systema Naturæ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systema_Naturae) is reckoned today as one of the "foundational texts" of scientific racism<sup>**[4]**</sup>, and defined the human race into five "varieties". Though not nearly as virulent as some of the others, and rather more scientific in his approach Linnæus nevertheless linked physical features to emotional, intellectual, and other psychological traits. This has led him to be regarded by some as "the original founding father of scientific racism"<sup>**[5]**</sup>.

The Reverend [**Robert Malthus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Robert_Malthus), more famous today for being the namesake of [Malthusianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malthusianism), refrained from more explicit forms of racism. Instead he railed against welfare, on the grounds that interfering with divinely ordained poverty perpetuates the "unfit" - a rhetoric we'll recognise today as [social Darwinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Darwinism). These concepts are credited with inspiring the classical definition of scientific racism<sup>**[6]**</sup> as formulated by Allan Chase, who in his 1980 work *Legacy of Malthus* calls him the founding father of scientific racism<sup>**[7]**</sup> - despite Malthus himself not emphasising race as a factor.

Lastly, there is the Jamaican planter [**Edward Long**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Long) who in 1774 published a vicious tirade describing Africans to be innately inferior to whites. He argued enslavement of Africans to be a necessity since they were too mentally, physically, and morally deficient to govern themselves - all very convenient for a planter relying on slave labour. Titled *History of Jamaica*, Long's work was devoid in scientific merits but widely read and and accepted, and now considered a pivotal development in scientific racism.

Sources:

<sub>**[1]** Nucci, Larry, ed. *Conflict, Contradiction, and Contrarian Elements in Moral Development and Education*. Psychology Press, 2005.</sub>
<sub>**[2]** Barkan, Elazar. *The Retreat of Scientific Racism
Changing Concepts of Race in Britain and the United States between the World Wars*. Cambridge University Press, 1992.</sub>
<sub>**[3]** van Galen Last, Rick, and Ralf Futselaar. *Black Shame: African Soldiers in Europe, 1914-1922.* Bloomsbury, 2015.</sub>
<sub>**[4]** Burton, Jonathan, and Ania Loomba. *Race in Early Modern England: A Documentary Companion.* Springer, 2007.</sub>
<sub>**[5]** http://www.saobserver.com/single-post/2017/04/18/Scientific-Racism</sub>
<sub>**[6]** "The perversion of scientific and historical facts to create the myth of two distinct races of humankind." - Allan Chase</sub>
<sub>**[7]** Brantlinger, Patrick. *Dark Vanishings: Discourse on the Extinction of Primitive Races, 1800-1930.* Cornell University Press, 2003.</sub>

Comment: I fail to see how Robert Malthus belongs here?

Comment: @Tlen I suggest reading Chase's book for a detailed treatment of that perspective. In short he helped birthed the idea of superior and inferior types of peoples and, framing it as a competition for limited resources, endorsed the tacit elimination of the latter. This inspired a generation of racists.

Comment: okay. I didn't ask about the origin of social Darwinism, but I see that those concepts may overlap.

Comment: @Tlen - Social Darwinism, at least here in the US, has always had a heavy racial component.

Comment: @T.E.D eugenics was quite popular before WWII, even today some think people with down syndrome don't deserve to be born.

Comment: @Tlen - Unless you are arguing that people are seriously worried that folks with Downs Syndrome are going to be having a lot of children and thus putting their material back into the gene pool (which seems unlikely to me, but I've been wrong before), then that has nothing whatsoever to do with Eugenics.

Comment: @T.E.D. I thing in USA even in the 60s the progressive though of scientific racism was tough at medical schools. I think people argue that people with Down syndrome are burden to society and world would be better without them.

Comment: @Tlen - Perhaps, but that's neither racism (Downs Syndrome is not a race), nor scientific. I suppose you could call it "Sociological Ableism", but that isn't what this question was asking about.

Comment: Re the reference to Edward Long's justification in this answer, I wonder if Long, in an age most educated people were familiar with Ancient Greek & Roman writers, was influenced by Aristotle's similar justification of slavery in his 'Politics'? Aristotle thought 'barbarians' which to the Ancient Greeks normally meant anyone not a Greek, were naturally suited to be slaves. To Greeks of that era, they were the only people who had established republican forms of government in which  citizens participated, showing that Greeks alone were suited to freedom.

Comment: 'Instead he railed against welfare, on the grounds that intervening with divinely ordained poverty perpetuates the "unfit"' I suppose he was also apposed to medicine and other things that keep the "unfit" alive, then.

Comment: Eugenics is the idea we should eliminate the unfit people.  Racism is a variant, that whole races are unfit.  Killing people with Downs Syndrome would still be eugenics, though not racism.

Comment: I remember reading an article in an anthropology magazine (by an anthropologist) dated in the 1890s basically saying "we need to figure out a way to stop these idiot missionaries from saying that the savages are human."

Comment: Well if those guys were idiots already... Mentally handicapped people oftentimes were sterilized, but I think only the Nazis killed them.